# RGB Cube app works very slowly when I create a big array

Tags: javafx

I want to make a RBG Cube. Every side of cube has 65 536 colors, so I made array with 65 536 rectangles (1 width and 1 height) (for one side) and every of rectangle has another color. My app works veeery slowly. When I run app I have to wait 2 minutes for the cube to appear. Can you help me what's wrong with my program?

My cube was about to rotate, which causes the program to stop again for 2 minutes.

This is my code that creates small rectangles and fills them with colors for one of sides (when G =255):

```
void makeCube(){
rectangle = new Rectangle[65536];

        for (int i = 0, w = 0, h = 0; i < rectangle.length; i++, w ++) {
            if (w == 256) {
                w = 0;
                h++;
            }
            rectangle[i] = new Rectangle(w, h, 1, 1);
            rectangle[i].setFill(Color.rgb(h, 255, w));
            rectangle[i].setTranslateZ(-100);
            rectangle[i].setRotationAxis(new Point3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
            rectangle[i].setRotate(0);
            group.getChildren().add(rectangle[i]);
        }
}
```

And this is my code that starts the application and rotates the cube:

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        group = new SmartGroup();
        scene = new Scene(group, WIDTH, HEIGHT, true);
        group.translateYProperty().set(HEIGHT / 2);
        group.translateXProperty().set(WIDTH / 2);
        group.translateZProperty().set(-120);
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.setTitle("RGB Cube");
        window.show();

        makeCube();

        camera = new PerspectiveCamera();
        scene.setCamera(camera);

        primaryStage.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
            switch (keyEvent.getCode()) {
                case NUMPAD8:
                    group.rotateByX(10);
                    break;
                case NUMPAD2:
                    group.rotateByX(-10);
                    break;
                case NUMPAD6:
                    group.rotateByY(10);
                    break;
                case NUMPAD4:
                    group.rotateByY(-10);
                    break;

            }
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("RGB Cube");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

I tried to allocate more memory in file idea64.exe.vmoptions in Intellij, but it still doesn't work. Maybe I do something wrong?

```
-server
-Xms512m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=2400m
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
```

Comment: Interacting with 6*256*256 nodes seems impractical. Some alternatives are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+3d+face+gradient).

Answer (score 0):

#### Don't render thousands of nodes

As noted in the comments, you should not add many thousands of nodes to the scene graph.

#### Use 3D for 3D objects

A cube is a 3D object.  JavaFX has hardware-accelerated 3D support, so it makes sense to render 3D objects.

A complete tutorial on how to create and use 3D objects in JavaFX is out of scope for a StackOverflow answer.  But I have added a simple example from which you could potentially learn.

#### Example

The example renders a texture based on your algorithm in the question that colors rectangles.  The texture is rendered by setting pixels on a `WritableImage`.  The texture is then [applied to a mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8) and displayed in a Scene.  Only a single face is rendered.  Individually coloring the sides of boxes is more complex, and I don't deal with that here.  The rendered face is rotated, so you can get an idea of how to animate the scene and what the performance of that is.

Because the example uses only a single node for the face that is rendered and the rendering is accelerated by graphic hardware, the performance is very quick compared to your original approach of rendering thousands of rectangles.

[image]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point3D;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class CubeApplication extends Application {
    private static final double WIDTH = 400, HEIGHT = 400;
    private static final float S = 256, HALF_S = S/2;
    public static final Duration ANIMATION_DURATION = Duration.seconds(10);

    private final MeshView meshView = loadMeshView();

    private MeshView loadMeshView() {
        float[] points = {
                -HALF_S, HALF_S, 0,
                -HALF_S, -HALF_S, 0,
                HALF_S, HALF_S, 0,
                HALF_S, -HALF_S, 0
        };
        float[] texCoords = {
                1, 1,
                1, 0,
                0, 1,
                0, 0
        };
        int[] faces = {
                2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0,
                2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1
        };

        TriangleMesh mesh = new TriangleMesh();
        mesh.getPoints().setAll(points);
        mesh.getTexCoords().setAll(texCoords);
        mesh.getFaces().setAll(faces);

        return new MeshView(mesh);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        PhongMaterial greenTexture = new PhongMaterial(
                Color.WHITE, createFaceTexture(), null, null, null
        );

        meshView.setMaterial(greenTexture);
        meshView.translateYProperty().set(HEIGHT / 2);
        meshView.translateXProperty().set(WIDTH / 2);
        meshView.setCullFace(CullFace.NONE);

        Group root = new Group(meshView);

        PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, WIDTH, HEIGHT, true, SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
        scene.setCamera(camera);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        rotate();
    }

    private void rotate() {
        RotateTransition rotate = new RotateTransition(ANIMATION_DURATION, meshView);
        rotate.setAxis(new Point3D(0, 1, 0));
        rotate.setFromAngle(0);
        rotate.setToAngle(360);
        rotate.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
        rotate.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        rotate.play();
    }

    private Image createFaceTexture(){
        WritableImage image = new WritableImage((int) S, (int) S);
        PixelWriter writer = image.getPixelWriter();
        for (int x = 0; x < S; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < S; y++) {
                writer.setColor(x, y, Color.rgb(y, 255, 2));
            }
        }

        return image;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Your image looks a lot like a `LinearGradient`, so, you could potentially apply that to a `Rectangle` that you [`snapshot`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot(javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,javafx.scene.image.WritableImage)) rather than creating a custom texture using a `PixelWriter`.

#### Reference Material

- [Rendering a 3D Box p25-30](https://www.slideshare.net/jpt1122/con2221-weaver-exploringjavafx3d).
- [How to color some triangles in a TriangleMesh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69305387/how-to-color-some-triangles-in-a-trianglemesh/69308521#69308521)
- [How to create custom 3d model in JavaFX 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459012/how-to-create-custom-3d-model-in-javafx-8)