# FXGL 3D adding images on entities

Tags: javafx, 3d, fxgl

I can't find a way to add PNG image as a surface to 3D box in FXGL.

I tried scavenging all the methods I can see that the Box class has but all I could find was setMaterial() method. I tried googling it but I only found a way to color the Box in one color using PhongMaterial class.
I still need a way to convert a PNG image from assets to usable Material on my Box.

Comment: A [`TriangleMesh`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/shape/TriangleMesh.html), for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+TriangleMesh+png), may be suitable.

Comment: That is done using a uv texture map of an image [diffuseMap property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/PhongMaterial.html#getDiffuseMap()) applied to the PhongMaterial.  You probably need a TriangeMesh instead of a Box.

Comment: You need to specify what the Box should look like.  Is it a cube? Should the same image appear on all sides? Is each side the same aspect ratio as the image?  If not, should the image be stretched?  Should the image instead wrap completely around all sides of the box?  The last is the default if you don't specify texture coordinates, but will probably look strange and not be what you want (you can find an example of that in the linked slide deck).

Comment: An [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61231437/how-to-create-such-shape-using-javafx-trianglemesh). An [explanation of how it works](http://www.lagers.org.uk/javafx/usemeshview.html). Study this [slide deck,](https://www.slideshare.net/jpt1122/con2221-weaver-exploringjavafx3d) specifically the area around slide 28 (Using TriangeMesh texture coordinates). Another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69305387/how-to-color-some-triangles-in-a-trianglemesh/69308521#69308521), slightly different, it colors the sides rather than applying different images to sides.